# Key error - while pivoting a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to pivot a dataframe which is like below.

```
twt=DataFrame(time_weekday_tip.groupby(["weekday", "time_hour"])["Tip_amount"].mean())
twt.reset_index()
print (twt.columns.tolist())
twt.columns = twt.columns.str.strip()
twt.pivot(index='time_hour', columns='weekday', values='Tip_amount')
```

[image]

But i get below error. Please advise.

```
pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)()

KeyError: 'time_hour'
```

Comment: `twt.reset_index()`  is not inplace. Replace it with `twt = twt.reset_index()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems some whitespace space in columns name, check it by:

```
print (twt.columns.tolist())
```

For remove it use [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
twt.columns = twt.columns.str.strip()
```

Also better is use parameter `values` in [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
twt.pivot(index='time_hour', columns='weekday', values='Tip_amount')
```

EDIT:

I think only [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) is necessary and remove another code:

```
 twt = time_weekday_tip.groupby(["weekday", "time_hour"])["Tip_amount"].mean().unstack(0)
```

---

EDIT2:

Another solution is add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to the end:

```
twt= time_weekday_tip.groupby(["weekday", "time_hour"])["Tip_amount"].mean().reset_index()
twt.pivot(index='time_hour', columns='weekday', values='Tip_amount')
```

---

```
twt= time_weekday_tip.groupby(["weekday", "time_hour"], as_index=False)["Tip_amount"].mean()
twt.pivot(index='time_hour', columns='weekday', values='Tip_amount')
```

Comment: I tried. still i get same error. I have added the list of lines which i executed before ending up in pivot.

Comment: Hmmm, `time_hour` is not duplicated? What return `print (twt.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: ['Tip_amount'] - Was the output

Comment: Glad can help you. Nice day!